# "overreleased while already deallocating"

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

With Xcode 8.0 / Swift 3.0, I'm trying to make a convenience init for NSRegularExpression, but my app crashes when I try to create an invalid regex.  I'm expecting it to throw an error, just like NSRegularExpression itself does.

Here's a minimal test case.  On the command line, instead of crashing, it just yells at me.

```
$ xcrun swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation 
  2.  
  3. extension NSRegularExpression { 
  4.     convenience init(foo: String, options: NSRegularExpression.Options) throws { 
  5.         try self.init(pattern: foo, options: options) 
  6.     } 
  7. } 
  8.  
  9. NSRegularExpression(foo: "(", options: [])
objc[63895]: NSRegularExpression object 0x100f01140 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
$E0: NSError = domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 2048 {
  _userInfo = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      key = "NSInvalidValue"
      value = "("
    }
  }
}
```

I've read "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)" chapters on Initialization, Extensions, and Error Handling, and I'm not understanding why this is overreleasing.  What's going on?

Is there a way to write such a convenience init for a designated initializer that throws, and have it automatically (re)throw the same Error?

Comment: No, I don't think there is provision for a `throws` convenience init defined in an extension. You might want to file a bug report at `bugs.swift.org`. The compiler should forbid this but we should not crash at runtime.